# getParameter(); returns null

Tags: java, javascript, json, get, null

My html looks like:

```
<form id="idForm3">
    <center>
        <fieldset style="width:30%;">
            <legend>Edit Elements:</legend>
                        Nome:<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" value="" name="TEXT_EDIT">&nbsp;
                        Preço:<input type="text" size="15" maxlength="15" value="" name="PRICE_EDIT"><br><br>
                        <input type="button" value="EDIT SELECTED" style="color:blue;"
                               onclick="var textSelected = document.getElementById('idSelect6').value;
                               editProductService(textSelected);">
         </fieldset>
     </center>
</form>
```

When I do:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/{text}")
public void getJson(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("text")String text) {
    boolean success;

    Tabela2colunasDTO.Produto produtoDTO;
    Tabela2colunasDTO dto = new Tabela2colunasDTO();

    produtoDTO = dto.getInstanceProduto();
    produtoDTO.text = text;
    produtoDTO.price = request.getParameter("PRICE_EDIT");

    System.out.println("request: "+ request.getParameter("PRICE_EDIT"));
    System.out.println("DTO text : "+produtoDTO.text);
    System.out.println("DTO price : "+produtoDTO.price);

    sucesso = (new ProdutosDAO()).doUpdate(produtoDTO);
    System.out.println("editar sucesso: "+success);


}
```

I'm trying to get the selected text and change its price in my database however `produtoDTO.price` is receiving null while `produtoDTO.text` works perfectly.

I suspect that GET doesn't work with `request.getParameter()`

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a GET, your parameter needs to be in the query string, similar to how you are passing in "text". So at the end of your URL:

> ?text=somthing&PRICE_EDIT=somethingElse

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem using POST method and adding a line `request.getParts();`

The actual code is:

```
    @POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("application/json")
@Path("/{text}")
public void postEditar3(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("text")String texto) {
    boolean sucesso;
    try {

        request.getParts();

        Tabela2colunasDTO.Produto produtoDTO;
        Tabela2colunasDTO dto = new Tabela2colunasDTO();

        produtoDTO = dto.getInstanceProduto();
        produtoDTO.text = text;
        produtoDTO.price = request.getParameter("PRICE_EDIT");


        success = (new ProdutosDAO()).doUpdate(produtoDTO);
        System.out.println("passou do sucesso doUpdate: "+success);

    } catch (IOException | ServletException e) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use @PathParam, you need a @QueryParam